# STL Multimap Remove/Erase Values

Tags: c++, stl

I have STL Multimap, I want to remove entries from the map which has specific value , I do not want to remove entire key, as that key may be mapping to other values which are required.

any help please.

Comment: A possible fix might be to swap the keys and values, this might not be an option for all reading this, but could be for some.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a specific pair from a C++ multimap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952476/how-to-remove-a-specific-pair-from-a-c-multimap)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand correctly these values can appear under any key. If that is the case you'll have to iterate over your multimap and erase specific values.

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, int> Multimap;
Multimap data;

for (Multimap::iterator iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end();)
{
    // you have to do this because iterators are invalidated
    Multimap::iterator erase_iter = iter++;

    // removes all even values
    if (erase_iter->second % 2 == 0)
        data.erase(erase_iter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks This works for me, I was looking for using remove_if algorithms.

Comment: I'm afraid `remove_if` from `<algorithm>` only works for containers where it is possible to reassign values (vector, deque, list - except suboptimal for the last) doing `*it1 = *it2`. This is not possible for map, as it might break the ordering.

Comment: @nietaki: No, the code does what the comments say. It removes all elements from the map where the value is even. Now remove your down-vote :)

Comment: @nietaki Why should it? Isn't it exactly equivalent to your example only introducing an additional temporary variable? In addition to Nikola's demand, deleting your obsolete answer would be appropriate, too.

Comment: I think putting `Multimap::iterator erase_iter = iter++;` in one statement is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11, *[std::multimap::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase)* returns an iterator following the last removed element.

So you can rewrite Nikola's answer slightly more cleanly without needing to introduce the local erase_iter variable:

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, int> Multimap;
Multimap data;

for (Multimap::iterator iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end();)
{
    // removes all even values
    if (iter->second % 2 == 0)
        iter = data.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

(See also answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511860/erasing-elements-in-a-multimap-while-iterating))