# Erasing elements in a multimap while iterating

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I'm writing a nodal path finding algorithm. I need to run through a multimap and delete elements out of it under certain conditions, but keep iterating through the multimap. Below is my code so far, it seems to work most of the time, but occasionally I get an error when doing nct_it++. Is it safe to erase the iterator pointer from the table before incrementing the iterator?

```
std::list<SinkSourceNodeConn>::iterator it;
std::multimap<SysNode*, SysNode*>::iterator nct_it;
SysNode* found_node = NULL;
nct_it = node_conn_table.begin();
while(nct_it != node_conn_table.end()) {

    // Find the node in the ever shrinking node connection table...
    if(nct_it->first == parent_node)
        found_node = nct_it->second;

    // Remove the table entry if we have found a node
    if(found_node) {
        // Search for the node in the expanded list. If it's not found, add it.
        bool found_the_node = false;
        for(it = m_sink_source_nodes_.begin(); it != m_sink_source_nodes_.end(); it++) {
            if(it->sink_source == sink_source && it->node == found_node)
                found_the_node = true;
        }
        if(!found_the_node) {
            recursion_list.push_back(found_node);
            recursion_list.unique();
            SinkSourceNodeConn ssnc;
            ssnc.node = found_node;
            ssnc.sink_source = sink_source;
            m_sink_source_nodes_.push_back(ssnc);
            if(found_node->GetPotential() < sink_source->GetPotential())
                found_node->SetPotential(sink_source->GetPotential());
        }
        found_node = NULL; // Unset the found node...
        node_conn_table.erase(nct_it);
        nct_it++;
    } else
        nct_it++;

}
```

Comment: Will `std::remove_if` not work for you?

Comment: Wouldn't that return the iterator to the end of the map, which would end my loop prematurely?

Comment: I don't understand. There is no loop with `std::remove_if`. It loops through the range that you specify in the call.

Comment: It would permaturely end this loop: while(nct_it != node_conn_table.end()) {

Comment: But with `std::remove_if`, you'd remove that loop and specify `node_conn_table.begin()` and `node_conn_table.end()` in the `remove_if` call.

Comment: I strong recommend you rethink about the logic of the code!! for example, `if(found_node) { nct_it++; } else { nct_it++; }` can be: `if(found_node) {} nct_it++;`

Comment: nct_it must be incremented whether found_node is true or not.

Comment: @jasonlg3d yes, your code is duplicating, also consider you have while,for,if loops in one function, the logic becomes horribly complicated, you need to break down small funcions

Comment: Not sure why the code isnt displaying indented...:/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it safe to erase the iterator pointer from the table before incrementing the iterator?

No, `erase` will invalidate the iterator and you shouldn't increment it after that.

To do this properly, make use of the return value of `erase` - the iterator following the last removed element:

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;

for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
   if (condition)
       it = m.erase(it);
   else
       ++it;
}
```

In C++03, `erase` returns nothing, so you have to do this manualy by saving a copy of the iterator and incrementing it before you erase the original:

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
typedef std::multimap<int, int>::iterator Iter;¸

for (Iter it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
   if ( /* some condition */ ) {
       Iter save = it;
       ++save;
       m.erase(it);
       it = save;
   } else
       ++it;
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply write `m.erase(it++);` instead of using a temporary variable?

Comment: @Kira Read the second line of this answer "No, `erase` will invalidate the iterator and you shouldn't increment it after that."

Comment: Actually `m.erase(it++)` will set the current value of `it` as argument to `erase`, increment it, and then call `erase` (with the pre-increment value), making it safe to call `m.erase(it++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this be better?

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
typedef std::multimap<int, int>::iterator Iter;¸

for (Iter it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
    if ( /* some condition */ ) {
        Iter save = it;
        ++it;
        m.erase(save);
    } else
       ++it;
}
```