# Efficient way to remove duplicates in a multimap?

Tags: c++, stl

What is the best way to remove duplicates in a large multimap in C++? For instance, I have a multimap, key <1,4> with its value 9 appears twice, how to get rid of it quickly? Thanks

```
...
<1,2> --> 3
<1,3> --> 7
<1,4> --> 9
<1,4> --> 9
...
```

I want it to to be

```
...
<1,2> --> 3
<1,3> --> 7
<1,4> --> 9
...
```

Comment: What map are you using? `std::map` doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: the decision on what you're *keeping* from the duplicates in a multimap would seem somewhat important to address first. If you want the last item inserted for each distinct key in the multimap, just copy it. Is the *value* identical for each identical key ?

Comment: can you be more clear on exactly what you want to remove, what counts as a "duplicate" in your mind

Comment: Sorry newbie here. Since `<1,4> --> 9` appear twice, they are exactly the same, why should I care which one to be removed?

Comment: Looks like you want to have multiple values, but just not duplicates so why not use map and save the values themselves in set

Comment: **Advice:** resolve the source issue, why is this item added twice to the list in the first place ? What you're asking for is a work-around, which is worse than having an Error in your code .. since it will conceal a deep issue that you won't be able to resolve later

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use map instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "set".

```
map<Point, set<int>> mymap;
mymap[1,2].insert(3);
mymap[1,3].insert(7);
mymap[1,4].insert(9);
mymap[1,4].insert(9);
//Print result.
for(auto itr = mymap.begin(); itr!=mymap.end(); itr++) {
  cout<<itr->first.x<<" "<< itr->first.y<<" ";
  for(set<int>::iterator vitr = itr->second.begin(); vitr != itr->second.end(); vitr++){
      cout<<(*vitr) +1<<" ";
  }
cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach that would take O(n) time is to copy your original map to a new map. For example,

```
multimap<T,U> original_map; 
multimap<T,U> new_map; 

while (original_map.size() > 0) 
{ 
    auto element = *(original_map.begin()); 
    new_map.insert(make_pair(element.first,element.second)); 
    original_map.erase(element.first); 
}
```

NOTE: This is assuming that criteria for duplicate entries are entries having only the same key.

Answer (score 1):

this [Erasing elements in a multimap while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511860/erasing-elements-in-a-multimap-while-iterating) is similar to what you are asking. Here is the in-place solution without additional allocations.

```
if (mymap.size() > 1) {
  auto prev_key = mymap.begin()->first;
  auto it = mymap.begin(); 
  for (++it; it != mymap.end();) {
    if (it->first == prev_key) {
      it = mymap.erase(it);
    } else {
      prev_key = it->first;
      ++it;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a note/caution: this erases entries where keys match, regardless of whether their values match.  It's unclear from the question whether that's what's wanted, or only duplicates for both key and value should be erased.

Comment: I agree with Tony Delroy, this answer doesn't remove only duplicate, but all key duplicate. Better to use a map in this case.